# Problems figuring out playing wav file

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

The task should be simple. I have an Image with a "Tapped" even handler, and i want to play a wav file when it is clicked.

```
<Image x:Name="Snd_abort_1" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Source="Assets/Tiles/A/abort_1.png" Tapped="Snd_abort_1_Tapped"></Image>

private void Snd_abort_1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement myMediaElement = new MediaElement();
        myMediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
        myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sounds/DukeNukem/abort.wav");
        myMediaElement.Play();
    }
```

[image]

For some particular reason this does not work. 
I tried to debug the click and that fires but no error, no sound.

I have tried both in emulator and on my Lumia 930 device.

What am i missing out?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Did i have tags in it? If so sorry. and thanks for correcting the title.

Comment: Yeah, you had "Problems figuring out playing wav file Windows mobile 8.1 C#", where "Windows mobile 8.1 C#" seemed more like metadata than like data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to prefix your files with `ms-appx:`, just do

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("Assets/Sounds/DukeNukem/abort.wav", UriKind.Relative);
myMediaElement.Play();
```

Unfortunately, though it is correct.  This code-behind approach will still not work.  Because the myMediaElement is not part of the VisualTree (because you made it dynamically).

To fix this, just add it to the root Grid/Panel

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("Assets/Sounds/DukeNukem/abort.wav", UriKind.Relative);
this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(myMediaElement);
myMediaElement.Play();
```

Now it should play nicely with everything.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, and for the tip about the prefix.  I named my RootElement which is a Grid, edited the uri line and attached the mediaelement but now i get an error saying "The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri". I have used an hour or so searching and debugging and cant figure it out, though it looks pretty self explanatory. The wav file is set to copy always (is copy necessary?), and the path looks correct. Any clues what this is?

Comment: I figured is out. I had the Autoplay set to false. When i set that to true it worked.